# Is there a way to do a 'project only' build or rebuild for a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

In Visual Studio 2005, you can right-click on a C++ project and choose `Project Only` > `Build Only [project]`.

Is there any way of doing the same for a C# project? If I choose `Build` from the project right-click menu, it builds all the dependencies too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily - if the dependencies have not changed then they will not be rebuilt.  If you select "ReBuild" then Visual Studio will rebuild the dependencies as well but you will find that a normal build will reuse the existing dependency assemblies if the source code for those assemblies is unchanged.

C# uses an assembly's *metadata* to build against.  This metadata is a part of the assembly itself and as such the entire assembly must be present at compilation time for the compiler to resolve any external types and their members.

Comment: Shame. My C++ dependencies still want to build themselves, even though they haven't changed - as you said, the C# ones seem not to.

Comment: As Ant has stated, If you have C++ projects & C# projects in the same solution rebuilding any C# project causes ALL C++ projects to rebuild - and expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not possible.

In C++, for dependencies, you only need headers. On C# you need the assemblies, then if they need to be rebuild, they will.

Comment: True, but suppose I know that the dependencies do not need to be rebuilt. There should be a "trust me" mode of just building one project.